# PHP Symfony - Autowiring Interface as constructor argument but using specific class from interface on test .env

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, dependency-injection, interface

Imagine we have the following Interface:

```
interface FooInterface {
//...
}
```

We have two classes that implements this interface:

```
class Foo implements FooInterface {
  //...
}

class Bar implements FooInterface {
  //...
}
```

In Symfony I want to inject the Interface and whenever I use FooInterface as DI in a constructor of a class I want the specific class "Foo". E.g.

```
class SomeClass {

  public function __construct(FooInterface $foo) { ... }

}
```

So far so good, now I want to inject the Class "Bar" only when Im on the test environement. (.env APP_ENV=test)

Is there a global config that I can use to specify which class will be injected based on the environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup parameters for different envs in `config/services.yaml:

```php
imports:
    - { resource: 'services_' ~ env('APP_ENV') ~ '.yaml' }
```

in `config/services_prod.yaml` set Foo as injected class

```php
Namespace\FooInterface: '@Namespace\Foo'
```

in `config/services_test.yaml` set Bar as injected class

```php
Namespace\FooInterface: '@Namespace\Bar'
```